# Combination of "checkboxes" and "dropdown list" on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in bioinformatics, I am making a graphical interface of a database with Tkinter. I need your help please. I am looking to make a drop down list with thousands of species names so I would like to make this list from a file. And then be able to select multiple species for a sequence download. for example to download the genomic sequences of "klebsiella pneumoniae" and "E.coli". So I would like to have combo boxes in the drop down list to be able to check off multiple species from the list.  I would like to have check boxes in the drop down box to be able to check more than one species in the list. Please could you help me to get a clearer picture and if it is possible also to tell me how I could associate to this selection, a button at the bottom with a "download" test, i.e. after having selected the species, the program is directed with this button.
I would like to ask you. Thank you very much

Comment: From a usability point of view this seems like a very bad idea. A dropdown with thousands of checkboxes would be almost completely unusable. It sounds like you would be much better off creating a dialog that permits some sort of searching and filtering.

Comment: If you want a dropdown with checkboxes, you are looking for a Menu widget. There, you can include checkboxes and radiobuttons and you can even include cascades to organize the species hierarchically. It would, however, make more sense to use a List widget and make it searchable, so you can look for entries and add them to the selection.